# How to redirect traffic?

Tags: networking, internet

In Kazakhstan, we have an Internet problem due to the terrorists. We can connect to the internet only for some period. Other times we can connect to only media websites such as [inform.kz](https://inform.kz), [qazaqstan.kz](http://qazaqstan.kz/), [tengrinews.kz](https://tengrinews.kz), and so on. So I want to redirect traffic when I connect to these sites when we do not access the whole internet. How can I implement that? I use M1 MacBook Pro, macOS BigSur.